# How do I add a Wordpress role that can only see scheduled and pending posts?

Tags: privacy, sharing

I run a WordPress installation. I'd like to let other people log in to view (and possibly edit), the scheduled and pending posts to check them over for spellings and the like, but not be able to view the draft posts (because they are very definitely a mess).

Google is unfortunately not helping. What's my best method for achieving this? A plugin, making all my drafts part of a particular private setting?

EDIT - I'll happily let them edit published posts as well, just not drafts...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugin that actually recognizes the differences between `pending_review`  and `published`, but I would recommend [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) as an easy way to manipulate viewing and editing rights.

It *does* offer a way to edit/view/discard private posts, which are effectively published posts but accessible only to those who have the URL. Might be worth considering.